# Add Certificate Authentication to Azure Function

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I need to add certificate authentication to my azure function app. I can see how to do this in a normal .net app with the following

```
// Configure the application to client certificate forwarded the frontend load balancer
        services.AddCertificateForwarding(options => { options.CertificateHeader = "X-ARR-ClientCert"; });

        // Add certificate authentication so when authorization is performed the user will be created from the certificate
        services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCertificate();
```

However these commands are not seemingly available in a function apps Program.cs...

How do I set up Certificate Authentication in the middleware for a function app?

Is just checking the Thumbprint and date values enough as that seems like if someone injected the public key into a malicious certificate then they could access the function? Or does Azure handle validating the keys and the app just needs to work out if it is the certificate we are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way i'm able to set up Certificate Authentication in the middleware for a function app

You'll need to create the following files:

1. **Middleware.cs**: This file contains the custom middleware that will perform certificate authentication.
2. **Startup.cs**: This file configures the middleware and sets up the authentication scheme.
3. **Function.cs**: This is the main Azure Function file.

**Step 1: Middleware.cs**
Created a file named `Middleware.cs` in your project directory:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    
    public class CertificateAuthenticationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly string expectedThumbprint = "YOUR_CERT_THUMBPRINT"; // Replace with the actual thumbprint of your client certificate.
    
        public CertificateAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
    
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var clientCert = context.Connection.ClientCertificate;
            if (clientCert != null && string.Equals(clientCert.Thumbprint, expectedThumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Step 2: Startup.cs**

Modify the `Startup.cs` file to configure the middleware and authentication scheme. Make sure to import the necessary namespaces:

```cs
    using certfunc;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Middleware;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    // Register your custom middleware here
                    services.AddTransient<CertificateAuthenticationMiddleware>();
                })
                .Build();
    
            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

**Step 3: Function.cs**

```cs
    using System.Net;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    
    namespace certfunc
    {
        public class Function1
        {
            private readonly ILogger _logger;
    
            public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
                _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
            }
    
            [Function("Function1")]
            public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    
                var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    
                response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
    
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Result**

[image]